# javascript. how to move selection on the top of a list

Tags: javascript, html

sry for my english. but i hope you can understand what my problem is.
i have a dropdown-menu where i have all letters from A to Z. in a list, i have a lot of names. when i select a letter in the dropdown menu, it should select the same letter in the list. that works so far, but how can i move the selected letter to the top of the list?

```html
<div align="center"><html>
 <head>
 <script language="JavaScript">
 function Eingabe(Wert)
 {
     for(i = 0; i < document.getElementById('Names').options.length; i++)
     {
         if(Wert.substr(0, Wert.length).toLowerCase() == document.getElementById('Names').options[i].value.substr(0, Wert.length).toLowerCase() && Wert.length != 0)
         {
             document.getElementById('Names').options[i].selected = true;
             break;
         }
     }
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <label>Select letter:
   <select name="Letters"onClick="Eingabe(this.value);" type="text"><br>
    <option>---Select letter---</option>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
    ...
   </select>
  </label>
  <br>
  <br>
 <select id="Names" size="18">
 <option value="A:">A:</option>
  <option value="Adena">&nbsp;-Adena</option>
 <option value="Adeodata">&nbsp;-Adeodata</option>
 <option value="Adeodato">&nbsp;-Adeodato</option>
 <option value="Adeodatus">&nbsp;-Adeodatus</option>
 <option value="Aderito">&nbsp;-Aderito</option>
 <option value="Adhelm">&nbsp;-Adhelm</option>
 <option value="Adil">&nbsp;-Adil</option>
 <option value="Adina">&nbsp;-Adina</option>
 <option value="Adine">&nbsp;-Adine</option>
 <option value="Adis">&nbsp;-Adis</option>
 <option value="Adlai">&nbsp;-Adlai</option>
 <option value="Admir">&nbsp;-Admir</option>
 <option value="Adnan">&nbsp;-Adnan</option>
 <option value="Adolar">&nbsp;-Adolar</option>
 <option value="Adolf">&nbsp;-Adolf</option>
 <option value="Adolfa">&nbsp;-Adolfa</option>
 <option value="Adolfine">&nbsp;-Adolfine</option>
 <option value="Adolfo">&nbsp;-Adolfo</option>
 <option value="Adolph">&nbsp;-Adolph</option>
 <option value="Adolpha">&nbsp;-Adolpha</option>
 <option value="Adolphe">&nbsp;-Adolphe</option>
 <option value="Adolphus">&nbsp;-Adolphus</option>
 <option value="Adone">&nbsp;-Adone</option>
 <option value="Adonia">&nbsp;-Adonia</option>
 <option value="Adonis">&nbsp;-Adonis</option>
 <option value="Adora">&nbsp;-Adora</option>
 <option value="Adoración">&nbsp;-Adoración</option>
 <option value="Adria">&nbsp;-Adria</option>
 <option value="Adriaan">&nbsp;-Adriaan</option>
 <option value="Adriaen">&nbsp;-Adriaen</option>
 <option value="Adrián">&nbsp;-Adrián</option>
 <option value="Adriana">&nbsp;-Adriana</option>
 <option value="Adriane">&nbsp;-Adriane</option>
 <option value="Adrianna">&nbsp;-Adrianna</option>
 <option value="Adrianne">&nbsp;-Adrianne</option>
 <option value="Adriano">&nbsp;-Adriano</option>
 <option value="B:">B:</option>
 <option value="Bartel">&nbsp;-Bartel</option>
 <option value="Barthold">&nbsp;-Barthold</option>
 <option value="Bartholomäa">&nbsp;-Bartholomäa</option>
 <option value="Bartholomaios">&nbsp;-Bartholomaios</option>
 <option value="Bartholomäus">&nbsp;-Bartholomäus</option>
 <option value="Bartholomew">&nbsp;-Bartholomew</option>
 <option value="Bartolmai">&nbsp;-Bartolmai</option>
 <option value="Bartolo">&nbsp;-Bartolo</option>
 <option value="Bartolomé">&nbsp;-Bartolomé</option>
 <option value="Bartolomea">&nbsp;-Bartolomea</option>
 <option value="Bartolomeo">&nbsp;-Bartolomeo</option>
 <option value="Bartosz">&nbsp;-Bartosz</option>
 <option value="Bas">&nbsp;-Bas</option>
 <option value="Bashkim">&nbsp;-Bashkim</option>
 <option value="Basia">&nbsp;-Basia</option>
 <option value="Basil">&nbsp;-Basil</option>
 <option value="Basile">&nbsp;-Basile</option>
 <option value="Basileios">&nbsp;-Basileios</option>
 <option value="Basilia">&nbsp;-Basilia</option>
 <option value="Basilisa">&nbsp;-Basilisa</option>
 <option value="Basilius">&nbsp;-Basilius</option>
 <option value="Basti">&nbsp;-Basti</option>
 <option value="Bastiaan">&nbsp;-Bastiaan</option>
 <option value="Bastian">&nbsp;-Bastian</option>
 <option value="Bastiano">&nbsp;-Bastiano</option>
 <option value="Bastien">&nbsp;-Bastien</option>
 <option value="Bathia">&nbsp;-Bathia</option>

 
 </select>
 </body>
 </html>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Element#scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView). Add the below line just before the `break` statement in your function `Eingabe`.

```
 document.getElementById('Names').options[i].scrollIntoView();
```

**EDIT:** Also change `onClick` to `onchange`. Refer working snippet added below.

```js
function Eingabe(Wert)
 {
     for(i = 0; i < document.getElementById('Names').options.length; i++)
     {
         if(Wert.substr(0, Wert.length).toLowerCase() == document.getElementById('Names').options[i].value.substr(0, Wert.length).toLowerCase() && Wert.length != 0)
         {
             document.getElementById('Names').options[i].selected = true;
        document.getElementById('Names').options[i].scrollIntoView();
             break;
         }
     }
 }
```

```html
<label>Select letter:
   <select name="Letters" onchange="Eingabe(this.value);" type="text"><br>
    <option>---Select letter---</option>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
   </select>
  </label>
  <br>
  <br>
 <select id="Names" size="18">
 <option value="A:">A:</option>
  <option value="Adena">&nbsp;-Adena</option>
 <option value="Adeodata">&nbsp;-Adeodata</option>
 <option value="Adeodato">&nbsp;-Adeodato</option>
 <option value="Adeodatus">&nbsp;-Adeodatus</option>
 <option value="Aderito">&nbsp;-Aderito</option>
 <option value="Adhelm">&nbsp;-Adhelm</option>
 <option value="Adil">&nbsp;-Adil</option>
 <option value="Adina">&nbsp;-Adina</option>
 <option value="Adine">&nbsp;-Adine</option>
 <option value="Adis">&nbsp;-Adis</option>
 <option value="Adlai">&nbsp;-Adlai</option>
 <option value="Admir">&nbsp;-Admir</option>
 <option value="Adnan">&nbsp;-Adnan</option>
 <option value="Adolar">&nbsp;-Adolar</option>
 <option value="Adolf">&nbsp;-Adolf</option>
 <option value="Adolfa">&nbsp;-Adolfa</option>
 <option value="Adolfine">&nbsp;-Adolfine</option>
 <option value="Adolfo">&nbsp;-Adolfo</option>
 <option value="Adolph">&nbsp;-Adolph</option>
 <option value="Adolpha">&nbsp;-Adolpha</option>
 <option value="Adolphe">&nbsp;-Adolphe</option>
 <option value="Adolphus">&nbsp;-Adolphus</option>
 <option value="Adone">&nbsp;-Adone</option>
 <option value="Adonia">&nbsp;-Adonia</option>
 <option value="Adonis">&nbsp;-Adonis</option>
 <option value="Adora">&nbsp;-Adora</option>
 <option value="Adoración">&nbsp;-Adoración</option>
 <option value="Adria">&nbsp;-Adria</option>
 <option value="Adriaan">&nbsp;-Adriaan</option>
 <option value="Adriaen">&nbsp;-Adriaen</option>
 <option value="Adrián">&nbsp;-Adrián</option>
 <option value="Adriana">&nbsp;-Adriana</option>
 <option value="Adriane">&nbsp;-Adriane</option>
 <option value="Adrianna">&nbsp;-Adrianna</option>
 <option value="Adrianne">&nbsp;-Adrianne</option>
 <option value="Adriano">&nbsp;-Adriano</option>
 <option value="B:">B:</option>
 <option value="Bartel">&nbsp;-Bartel</option>
 <option value="Barthold">&nbsp;-Barthold</option>
 <option value="Bartholomäa">&nbsp;-Bartholomäa</option>
 <option value="Bartholomaios">&nbsp;-Bartholomaios</option>
 <option value="Bartholomäus">&nbsp;-Bartholomäus</option>
 <option value="Bartholomew">&nbsp;-Bartholomew</option>
 <option value="Bartolmai">&nbsp;-Bartolmai</option>
 <option value="Bartolo">&nbsp;-Bartolo</option>
 <option value="Bartolomé">&nbsp;-Bartolomé</option>
 <option value="Bartolomea">&nbsp;-Bartolomea</option>
 <option value="Bartolomeo">&nbsp;-Bartolomeo</option>
 <option value="Bartosz">&nbsp;-Bartosz</option>
 <option value="Bas">&nbsp;-Bas</option>
 <option value="Bashkim">&nbsp;-Bashkim</option>
 <option value="Basia">&nbsp;-Basia</option>
 <option value="Basil">&nbsp;-Basil</option>
 <option value="Basile">&nbsp;-Basile</option>
 <option value="Basileios">&nbsp;-Basileios</option>
 <option value="Basilia">&nbsp;-Basilia</option>
 <option value="Basilisa">&nbsp;-Basilisa</option>
 <option value="Basilius">&nbsp;-Basilius</option>
 <option value="Basti">&nbsp;-Basti</option>
 <option value="Bastiaan">&nbsp;-Bastiaan</option>
 <option value="Bastian">&nbsp;-Bastian</option>
 <option value="Bastiano">&nbsp;-Bastiano</option>
 <option value="Bastien">&nbsp;-Bastien</option>
 <option value="Bathia">&nbsp;-Bathia</option>

 
 </select>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, but it didnt help. it jumps to the selected index at the bottom of my list, just like before. i tried something that works (like a beginner): document.getElementById('Modell').options[i].selected = true;
   var index = document.getElementById('Modell').selectedIndex;
   document.getElementById('Modell').selectedIndex = index + 18;
   var index = document.getElementById('Modell').selectedIndex;
   document.getElementById('Modell').selectedIndex = index - 18;
   break;

Comment: @tim-palermo i've added the whole snippet for your reference. it's working with the method `scrollIntoView()`. also change the `onClick` event to `onchange` to prevent unnecessary event firing.